# How To Disable Directory File Listing With Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have a website example: example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css

I want this directory to redirect to the homepage (index) when it is searched in other not to display my CSS code

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: You can't do that. The CSS needs to be public in order for your site to work.

Comment: The best you can probably do is minify it, that will make it harder to read and has a few other benefits.  But you cannot prevent a client from getting the CSS as it is need to render the page, and it typically gets cashed too (which happens on the client).  So even if you could prevent them from seeing it through a browser request (which you cant) a user could just look at it in the cache.

Comment: The title `How to disable directly listing` is very misleading (because that is a different thing).  For that you either put an index file in the folder or better yet turn it off in apache or in HTACESS `Options -Indexes`

Comment: Thank you all for your response. @ArtisticPhoenix, when I turn it off using htaccess, what happens? hope it won't affect the CSS rending on the site?

Comment: The directory listing is the default index, when no index page exists, it shows the folders and any files at the current level.  Basically it's a file navigation system and has nothing to do with CSS, which is why your title is misleading.  Please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71523/how-do-i-stop-folder-structure-from-being-visible-in-browser-directory-listing

Comment: Then what about something like: example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/page.php

I will like it to redirect to the index when it is searched, instead of a blank page